# How can I write a SQL query to group employees by salary range?

Tags: sql, database

I am learning database query and want to find out the following SQL query from the HR Schema in Oracle database.

Find number of employees in each salary group. Salary groups are considered as follows.

Group 1: 0k to <5K, 5k to <10k, 10k to <15k, and so on.

what will be the possible query code ??

Tables are as follows: There are seven tables in total

1. `REGIONS`: `REGION_ID, REGION_NAME`
2. `COUNTRIES`: `COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME, REGION_ID`
3. `LOCATIONS`: `LOCATION_ID, STREET_ADDRESS, POSTAL_CODE, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, COUNTRY_ID`
4. `DEPARTMENTS`: `DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, MANAGER_ID, LOCATION_ID`
5. `EMPLOYEES`: `EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID`
6. `JOB_HISTORY`: `EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID`
7. `JOBS`: `JOB_ID, JOB_TITLE, MIN_SALARY, MAX_SALARY`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more information to your question - sample database tables, expected output, and most importantly - what have you tried?! People are more likely to help if you demonstrate that you have made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

You'll use a case statement to do this. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN salary BETWEEN 0 and 5000 THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN salary BETWEEN 5001 and 10000 THEN 'Group2'
        ... and on and on ...
        END as PayGroup
FROM
    <yourtable>
```

Might be a good idea to read up on basic T-SQL commands before venturing much further as this is like SQL 101 territory right here.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide some details about the database schema you are using?

- What tables do exist
- What columns do they have

I assume you want an output like

group 1: xx Employees
group 2: yy Employees

**Is that correct?
Ok this should be it then:**

```
select 
    case
        when salary BETWEEN 0 and 5000 then "Group 1"
        when salary BETWEEN 5001 and 50000 then "Group 2"
        when salary BETWEEN 50001 and 500000 then "Group 3"
    end as salary_group, count(*) as employees_count
from employes group by salary_group
```

you can of course change the numbers and group names!

Comment: what does your schema look like?
do you have a table like 'salary_groups' and 'employees' where the 'employees' have something like a 'salary_group_id' col?

Answer (score -1):

The following code may solve your problem:

```
create table #temp
(
  EmpName nchar(10),
  EmpSal nchar(10)
)
insert into #temp(EmpName, EmpSal)
(select  
    EmpName,
        case
        when [EmpSalary] BETWEEN 0 and 5000 then 'Group1'
        when [EmpSalary] BETWEEN 5001 and 10000 then 'Group2'
        when [EmpSalary] BETWEEN 10001 and 15000 then 'Group3'
        when [EmpSalary] between 15001 and 20000 then 'Group4'
        end as [EmpSalary] 
     from [dbo].[Employee])

     select EmpSal, count(*) as 'Group by Salary Range' from #temp
     group by EmpSal
```

Please change column Types as per your requirement.